# NiceEdit Image tag change end to />

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nicedit

I am using NiceEditor, where I create an html page and save it in a file, after saving it I simply convert it to pdf using pdfcrowd api (https://pdfcrowd.com/) , but the problem with pdfcrowd convert all other images are added to the pdf on creation but the ones I added on the html file created are'nt, and the only difference I see is that the images I added using jquery nicEdit do not end with /> but rather just >, for example:

```
<img src="http://website.dev/images-custom/d5bebac841d9e78b7e09af9c839e6b03.jpg" width="206">
```

So the question is, how do I, in nicEdit, change the ending of the above image to end with `"width='206' />` instead of `"width='206'>`?

Comment: These endings are used in XHTML, so you might find something in the documentation about that.

Comment: Have you tried reading their documentations? They might have the condition where code is changed to the above code.